# Is there a way to determine if any thread is waiting on a given conditional variable?

Tags: c, posix, condition-variable

Posix page on [pthread_cond_destroy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_destroy.html) says "*Attempting to destroy a condition variable upon which other threads are currently blocked results in undefined behavior.*"

How can it be ascertained if any thread is really waiting on the condition variable? Even if the condition associated with the condition variable is true, that doesn't necessarily mean that a thread is waiting for that condition on a condition variable.

So, while calling pthread_cond_destroy, how to ascertain if there is a need to wake up a thread or not?

Comment: Typically, it's easier to just not destroy some things, especially threads and synchro objects, unless you are an OS and terminating a process.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to structure your code in a manner so you know that there is no, and will not be in the future, any threads that uses the cond variable, so you can destroy it.

There's no function to query whether a cond variable is currently in use (or if any thread is going to use it in a second or 50).